# electronic signature with php

Tags: php, mysql, cryptography, signature

In my app, clients agree to contracts.

I need some way of ensuring that their approval of a contract cannot be interfered with even if one has access to the mysql database.

In other words, their approval can be linked to the terms they have approved.

It has to be legally binding so if the data in the db is tampered with, the signature would no longer be valid.

Has anyone accomplished this?

Comment: "if the data in the db is tampered with, the signature would no longer be valid." That renders your solution useless, correct?

Comment: Well, no, I dont have a solution. I am asking if anyone has a solution to this problem.

Comment: A simple way to do it would be an MD5 (or other hash) of the data in the database. That will tell you if the data has changed. I have no idea what a court would do with that (which is, ultimately, what determines if it's "legally binding").

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was looking at hashing the data, and I agree that any electronic solution can be tampered with. Just need the solution to be compliant with the laws on electronic signatures. Fundamentally its a PDF or other file that is uploaded, and the client indicates an approval of the file to an extent where the approval cant be reversed and the original file to which the approval relates can't then be interfered with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking questions about cryptography on Stack Overflow, you're in over your head and will undoubtedly make a minor but important mistake that renders your work completely invalid. Cryptography is very hard to get completely correct, and even then you will have to keep your application up-to-date as various new techniques to circumvent things are discovered.

Use an off-the-shelf solution that's **proven** to work like [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) to handle your signing. Even then you'll need to ensure it's installed correctly, that you're handling the data correctly and calling the correct functions to validate the signatures.

Long story short: Find someone qualified and/or certified to do this and follow their advice *to the letter*. Get their solution vetted by a third party that can be trusted.

What you want to do here in general terms is get both parties to cryptographically sign the contents of the original message. That way in order to change the contents, both parties would have to "collude", something that's not likely if one party is trying to sabotage the other.

This requires both parties to have a secured, unknown private key that's used for these operations. Managing these is *considerable* overhead for your application unless you have a way of installing client software that does it for them. Even then, generating and protecting keys is anything but fun.

If you want to learn more about the nuances of cryptography, you will need to read [The Book](https://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html).